# How to use pretty photo (jquery gallery plugin) with jsf?

Tags: jquery, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to integrate [prettyPhoto jquery plugin](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) with jsf and don`t know how to call prettyphoto function. When the document is loaded I want to show photo gallery when user cliks on the image. I have written a code like this:

```
<script src="/iHome-war/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/iHome-war/styles/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" 
charset="utf-8" />
<script src="/iHome-war/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
...
<h:form id="soForm">
<div class="articleContent">
<div class="galleryPhoto">
<h:commandLink action="/userimages/22/0.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto">
<h:graphicImage url="/userimages/22/0.jpg" width="120" height="90" alt="photo"/>
</h:commandLink></div></div></h:form> 
...
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#soForm\\:commandLink[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();});
</script>
```

but it doesn`t work. So the question is how to call this function to make it work? I know that JSF names consists of two elements formid:componentid but how to use that information? Thanks for replies.

Comment: Hint: when writing JavaScript/jQuery, do not look at JSF source code, but look at its generated HTML output (simply because that's all which JS has access to). Rightclick page in browser and choose *View Source* to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem is that the "commandLink" construct is a server-side thing that will be gone by the time the Javascript code runs at the client.  You therefore need to change the selector:

```
$("#soForm *[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
```

I don't know what "commandLink" generates on the page, but if you find that it's an `<a>` tag you could replace that "*" by "a".

Comment: It's an `<a>` element. So, definitely use `a`.

Answer (score 0):

jsf has a `forceId` attribute that you can use to force the id of the element you want to run that function on, after you do that your selector becomes

```
jQuery("#THE_ID").prettyPhoto()
```